# animate height with jquery of div with box-sizing: border-box

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, border

Is ther a way to animate a div with following style correctly?

```
.div1{
 background-color: red;
 padding: 5px;
 margin: 5px;
 width: 100%;
 border: 4px solid #000 !important;
 border-radius: 8px;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 height: 200px;
}
```

I need every css-style given here. My problem is that there is a offset error when the animation starts (as you can see here http://jsfiddle.net/q5bmf/1/, when the example is loaded there is a animation from somewhere to 200px). The example works if I hide one ore more css-styles, but I don't want to. So is there a way to make jquery work correctly?

Comment: Why are you using css to set the height, and then also animating the height with jQuery? Like you said, it works fine if you remove the height css attribute.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve? You are animating the height form 200px to 200px? And is the 'border-box' realy nessacary here? The browser support is not very good in my experience, definitly when you start animating.

Comment: In CSS, the border thickness is added to the height. jQuery uses this box model, so you're seeing the combined top and bottom border thicknesses being animated. Since your border thickness is 4px, the function is animating from 200px to 208px. I'd change the box-sizing type or add the 8px to your function.

Comment: @ZackT. I am using css for the initial size. When I remove the initial size the problem is not visible, but it is still there.

Comment: @PeterVR I am animating from 200px to 200px because this was the easisest way to shot the problem. It is only a minimalistic example. border-box is nessacary because I am using width of 100%.

Comment: @isherwood If I change box-sizing type I will have to set the width of 100% programmatically. Maybe this is the only solotion...

Comment: Your problem is not clearly defined. What is the effect you are trying to achieve?

Comment: You can just set the width to auto (or not set a width at all, cause auto is default) and the box will nicely fit into it's parent. Still don't see why you need the border-box...